# DB2 Join returns multiple duplicates

Tags: sql, db2

I have a pretty simple select query in db2 where I only want one distinct record from the left table (emps) but by adding the managers table for the managerName I get duplicate records because the managers table can have multiple rows of managers assigned to the same employee.

```
SELECT DISTINCT number, name, status, managerNum, m.managerName
from emps e
left outer join managers m
    on e.managerNum = m.managerNum
group by number, name, status, managerNum, m.managerName;
```

Is there a way I can make sure I only get my single records from the left table, and only get the managerName for each one? In other words, I should only have one record  per 'number';

Example of table data:

emps

```
number | name | status | managerNum
-----------------------------------
123      Emp1   Active    321
```

managers

```
empNumber | managerNum | managerName | location
-----------------------------------------------
123           321          manager        1
123           321          manager        2aa
```

Comment: Hint:  `ON` clause.

Comment: What is your `JOIN` condition ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure why that didn't copy over. fixed now

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: How do you decide *which* manager to use, if an employee has 2 or more managers. Or do you care?

Comment: Strange statement: "managers table can have multiple rows of managers assigned to the same employee". Can you provide an example of data in both tables for this case?

Comment: The managers are assigned to multiple employees but there may be 2 records for emp 123 and manager 1 because there is a record for each location

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I've updated with a simple example of table data

Comment: Then add additional join condition on location (you have to decide *which* location row to use).  Understand the data model first.

Comment: But some managers might have locations 1 and 2, some only 3 and 4. Not every manager record will have one of those for sure. I want a single record regardless of location

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Which manager do you want to show when there are multiple ones for the employee?

Comment: Neither specifically, because all other data besides location is irrelevant. Basically the first record would suffice

Comment: Oh... your database modeling ain't great man.

Comment: @TheImpaler trust me i know haha. We're refactoring it but this is to pull some data in the meantime. I didn't build it which is why I'm not sure how to attack this specifically, especially it being DB2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arbitrary manager from a number of them:

```
with emp (number, name, status, managerNum) as (values 
  (123, 'Emp1', 'Active', 321)
)
, managers (empNumber, managerNum, managerName, location) as (values 
  (123, 321, 'manager', '1')
, (123, 321, 'manager', '2aa')
)
SELECT e.number, e.name, e.status, e.managerNum, m.managerName
from emp e
left join table(select managerName from managers m where m.managerNum=e.managerNum fetch first 1 row only) m on 1=1;
```

Comment: `fetch first 1 row only` is unstable in the absence of `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Upvoting since the database is not normalised and the query returns the expected value.